# I want to add two subfigures one under the other, but the code I added below gives an error. I can't find why this code does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}

\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.15cm, fill=black}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (1.5,-1.5) {};
    \node (C) at (3,0) {};
    \node (D) at (1.5,1.5) {};
    \node (E) at (1.5,3) {};
    \node (F) at (1.5,-3) {};
    \node (G) at (3,2) {};
    
    \node (H) at (4.5,1.5) {};
    \node (I) at (6,0) {};
    \node (J) at (4.5,-1.5) {};
    \node (K) at (4.5,-3) {};
    \node (L) at (4.5,3) {};
    \node (M) at (6,3) {};
    \node (N) at (6,1.5) {};
    
    \node (O) at (7.5,1.5) {};
    \node (P) at (7.5,-1.5) {};
    \node (R) at (9,1.5) {};
    
    \draw[blue,thick,dashed] (4.5,0) ellipse (5.5cm and 3.5cm);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \draw[-latex] (A) edge[bend right=15] (B);
    \draw[-latex] (B) edge[bend right=15] (C);
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right=15] (B);
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right=15] (D);
    \draw[-latex] (D) edge[bend right=15] (A);
    \draw[-latex] (E) edge (D);
    \draw[-latex] (B) edge (F);
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right=15] (G);
    \draw[-latex] (G) edge[bend right=15] (C);
    \draw[-latex] (G) edge[bend right=15] (D);
    \draw[-latex] (D) edge[bend right=15] (G);
    
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend left=15] (H);
    \draw[-latex] (H) edge[bend left=15] (I);
    \draw[-latex] (I) edge[bend left=15] (J);
    \draw[-latex] (J) edge[bend left=15] (C);
    
    \draw[-latex] (H) edge[bend right=15] (L);
    \draw[-latex] (H) edge (M);
    \draw[-latex] (L) edge[bend right=15] (H);
    \draw[-latex] (M) edge[bend right=15] (L);
    \draw[-latex] (L) edge[bend right=15] (M);
    \draw[-latex] (K) edge (J);
    \draw[-latex] (M) edge (N);
    \draw[-latex] (N) edge (I);
    
    \draw[-latex] (I) edge[bend right=15] (P);
    \draw[-latex] (O) edge[bend right=15] (I);
    \draw[-latex] (M) edge (O);
    \draw[-latex] (O) edge (R);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.15cm, fill=black}]
    \node (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node (B) at (1.5,-1.5) {};
    \node (C) at (3,0) {};
    \node (D) at (1.5,1.5) {};
    \node (E) at (1.5,3) {};
    \node (F) at (1.5,-3) {};
    \node (G) at (3,2) {};

    \node (H) at (4.5,1.5) {};
    \node (I) at (6,0) {};
    \node (J) at (4.5,-1.5) {};
    \node (K) at (4.5,-3) {};
    \node (L) at (4.5,3) {};
    \node (M) at (6,3) {};
    \node (N) at (6,1.5) {};

    \node (O) at (7.5,1.5) {};
    \node (P) at (7.5,-1.5) {};
    \node (R) at (9,1.5) {};

    \draw[blue,thick,dashed] (4.5,0) ellipse (5.5cm and 3.5cm);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
    \draw[-latex] (A) edge[bend right=15] (B);
    \draw[-latex] (B) edge[bend right=15] (C);
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right=15] (B);
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right=15] (D);
    \draw[-latex] (D) edge[bend right=15] (A);
    \draw[-latex] (E) edge (D);
    \draw[-latex] (B) edge (F);
    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right=15] (G);
    \draw[-latex] (G) edge[bend right=15] (C);
    \draw[-latex] (G) edge[bend right=15] (D);
    \draw[-latex] (D) edge[bend right=15] (G);

    \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend left=15] (H);
    \draw[-latex] (H) edge[bend left=15] (I);
    \draw[-latex] (I) edge[bend left=15] (J);
    \draw[-latex] (J) edge[bend left=15] (C);

    \draw[-latex] (H) edge[bend right=15] (L);
    \draw[-latex] (H) edge (M);
    \draw[-latex] (L) edge[bend right=15] (H);
    \draw[-latex] (M) edge[bend right=15] (L);
    \draw[-latex] (L) edge[bend right=15] (M);
    \draw[-latex] (K) edge (J);
    \draw[-latex] (M) edge (N);
    \draw[-latex] (N) edge (I);

    \draw[-latex] (I) edge[bend right=15] (P);
    \draw[-latex] (O) edge[bend right=15] (I);
    \draw[-latex] (M) edge (O);
    \draw[-latex] (O) edge (R);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{SCC Minimal}
\label{SCC minimal}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please tell us whether you use the `subcaption`, `subfig`, or `subfigure` package. You mention getting an error message. Do please share with us what this error message says. And, do please let us know which tikz-related packages you employ; it's absolutely no fun to go through a whole host of packages.

Comment: i think you have to remove the empty line between the two subfigures, or put a % at,the beginning of it.

Comment: Error messages: ! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.                                        
 l.84 \begin{subfigure}
? 
! LaTeX Error: \begin{center} on input line 82 ended by \end{subfigure}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                            
l.144 \end{subfigure}

Comment: removing the empty line or inserting % did not help. I still receive the same error messages. I have not used subcaption, subfig, or subfigure packages. I employ the following tikz related packages: \usepackage{tikz}, \usepackage{graphicx}.

Comment: @Sechkin - The `subfigure` environment is *not* defined in the LaTeX kernel. Therefore, if you don't load `subcaption` (or `subfig` or `subfigure`), there should definitely be no surprise at all about `\begin{subfigure}` throwing an error message.

Comment: Dear Mico, thank you very much for your suggestions. I added subcaption environment, it has not worked. But then I applied your suggestion \begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth} and it compiled. Thank you very much. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you report says that the `subfigure` environment isn't defined. Since the `subfigure` environment isn't defined in the LaTeX kernel and you don't load either `subcaption`, `subfig`, or `subfigure`, it can't be much of a surprise that LaTeX has to issue an error message.

If you *were* using the `subcaption` package, you would next have to replace both instances of `\begin{subfigure}` with `\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}`.

That said, I'd omit both `subfigure` wrappers entirely, i.e., I'd remove both instances of `\begin{subfigure}` and both instances of `\end{subfigure}`. A `subfigure` environment is just a `minipage` environment that happens to know what to do in case it encounters a `\caption` statement in its scope. Since you don't make use of the `subfigure` machinery, why clutter up your code needlessly?